# For all files that does not contain a string, prepend a string to the file

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to iterate through a list of html files, check to see if `{% load static from staticfiles %}` exists in the file and **if it does not exists**, prepend `{% load static from staticfiles %}` to it.

This is what I have now on 1 file called `job/home.html` (for testing purposes before applying it to all files):

`grep -q '{% load static from staticfiles %}' job/home.html || sed -i '' 's+{% load static from staticfiles %}\n+' job/home.html`

So 2 things,

- How can I make this command recursive for all the html files
- The line break, `\n` doesn't seem to be line breaking

Comment: What is the '' for?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, which should return a recursive result

```
find /home/user/myfolder -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    yourcommands with "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```

More about find and lots of examples on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find and also a few different things in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find

Comment: Nice edit Stephane, especially appreciated the wiki change notes

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
find /home/user/myfolder -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
    fgrep &>/dev/null "{% load static from staticfiles %}" "$1" ||
        sed -i '1i {% load static from staticfiles %}!' "$1"
' -- {} \;
```

Comment: I'm getting `find: home.html: unknown option`

Comment: You need to quote your glob expansion.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you have [`bash` 4 or newer](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges) you can use `shopt -s globstar` to enable recursive globs (among other things):

```
... job/**/*.html
```

(thanks @evilsoup!)

This glob will resolve to all `.html` files anywhere inside `job/` (don't be mislead by the second slash; it looks like the glob is actually `**/`).

To [add text to the beginning of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54381/96588) semi-safely:

```
echo "text" | cat - yourfile > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out yourfile
```

A safer solution would be to use a random temp directory, to avoid almost any other processes interfering with this one:

```
dir="$(mktemp -d)" && echo "text" | cat - yourfile > "$dir/out" && mv "$dir/out" yourfile
```

Comment: You actually need to use `job/**/*.html` (the bash version of globstar is rather limited).